# Substring empezando por el final

Tags: php

Necesito separar la cadena, quitar los espacios en blanco y la flecha, solo quiero quedarme con las etiquetas, cada una en una variable diferente.
La primera si me sale pero la segunda ya no.

```
$str = 'PD/R --> PPA';
$parte_1 = substr($str,0,strrpos($str, "-")-2).'<br>';
$parte_2 = substr($str, -2);
```

Estas etiquetas pueden variar, por ejemplo: `'F --> A' ó 'F --> FJ'`. Reitero, solo quiero quedarme con las dos etiquetas.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta:

```
 $tags = explode(' --> ',$str);
 echo $tags[0].", ".$tags[1];
```

referencia completa de [explode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Comment: Epico! Funciona Gracias.

Comment: si te sirvió, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: No pensé en hacer el explode de la flecha entera. Me gusta mucho más tu solución. +1 :)

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob si esto responde a tu pregunta, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el **✔️** que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta (no se te descuenta nada por eso, todo lo contrario ambos ganan reputación).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función **[explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)** para dividir tu string tomando como referencia el espacio. Una vez hecho esto, coger la primera y tercera posición del array generado:

```
$str = 'PD/R --> PPA';
$partes = explode(" ",$str);
$parte1 = $partes[0]; //PD/R
$parte2 = $partes[2]; //PPA
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo más, pero esta vez con [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php):

```
$string = 'PD/R --> PPA';
$arrayString = preg_split('/-->\s/', $string); // "\s" elimina los espacios

$parte_1 = $arrayString[0];
$parte_2 = $arrayString[1];

echo $parte_1; //=> PD/R
echo $parte_2; //=> PPA
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0b2dd73df7b444df97cfd3bded303ae917caa36)